# How to copy bytes from a ctypes Structure to a buffer created from create_string_buffer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a ctypes structure (for example):

```
from ctypes import *
class Foo(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('f1',c_uint),
               ('f2',c_uint)]
```

I would like to copy an instance of that structure in to a buffer that was created from create_string_buffer (that is larger in size than needed for a single instance of Foo).

Example:

```
f = Foo()
f.f1=1; f.f2=2;
buf = create_string_buffer(100)
buf[0:sizeof(f)] = f
```

I know you can read and write data to/from structures on file objects (i.e. open('bar','rb').readinto(f) ), so it seems that there should be some way to do this easily too...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Avoid using an operation that makes a temporary copy, or that creates temporary objects while iterating. This should be a direct copy from the source buffer to the target buffer. It's simplest to use `ctypes.memmove`:

```
f = Foo()
f.f1=1
f.f2=2

buf = (c_char * 100)()
memmove(buf, byref(f), sizeof(f))
```

Or use a temporary array created with `from_buffer` (not a copy):

```
memoryview(buf)[:sizeof(f)] = (c_char * sizeof(f)).from_buffer(f)
```

The latter doesn't work in Python 3, however. It should work, but the buffer format codes that ctypes uses aren't supported by `memoryview`.

If you wanted a new array that was the same size or smaller, you could use the array type's `from_buffer_copy` method (2.6+):

```
buf = (c_char * sizeof(f)).from_buffer_copy(f)
```

Comment: What if I want to do it the other way around? A buffer into a ctype structure with a size and data.

Comment: @marsh, use `memmove` to copy data into an existing struct, but if you're creating a new instance, try the `from_buffer_copy` constructor instead.

Comment: You can use `memoryview(buf).cast('B')` to discard the unwanted format code.